# Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "dialog-overview-example-dialog" did not match any elements

Tags: dialog, angular-material2, angular5

There is an example of using `mat-dialog` in Angular Material [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gaoqbmrxakr)

The problem is, in this example, there is a selector 'dialog-content-example-dialog' which is never used and as a result, I see this error in console:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "dialog-overview-example-dialog" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The selector "dialog-overview-example-dialog" did not match any elements`

if I add that selector to the HTML, I will get this error:

`"Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[MatDialogRef]: StaticInjectorError[MatDialogRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution!

in that example, they added `DialogResultExampleDialog` to `bootstrap` in `main.ts` like:

`bootstrap: [DialogResultExample, DialogResultExampleDialog]`

but the solution is:

```
bootstrap: [DialogResultExample],
entryComponents: [DialogResultExampleDialog]
```

and it works very well without any console error.